# Is it legal to use code written for a customer's app for a personal business app?

Tags: legal

I have written a web app for a client. In our contract we have it explicity written that we retain rights to all of the code within the app. Is it legal to repurpose that code for a similar app that we would change and then sell to future customers?

Comment: **I am not a lawyer, and you really need to consult with one**. It looks like, since you're retaining the code rights (and you're essentially perpetually licensing it to your client), it'd be legal to re-purpose that code.

Answer (score 3):

Your contract explicitly states that you retain rights to all code, but what kind of **license** did you provide your client? If it's an **exclusive** license, I don't think you can reuse the code until the license expires, unless you didn't grant worldwide rights under the license and the new use is in a region not covered by the license.